# How to prove $(0,1) \times \mathbb{R} \, , \, (0,2) \times \mathbb{R}$ are not isometric?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, isometry, metric-geometry

I am trying to prove in an elementary way that $X_1=(0,1) \times \mathbb{R} \, , \, X_2=(0,2) \times \mathbb{R}$ (with the standrad euclidean metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$) are not isometric as metric spaces.

One way to do this is to prove they are not isometric as Riemannian manifolds, and then use [Myers–Steenrod theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Steenrod_theorem). To see they are not isometric as Riemannian manifolds, note that in $X_2$ there are pairs of orthogonal geodesic segments, one with length arbitrarily close to $2$ (horizontal) and the other (vertical) arbitrarily long.

This is impossible in $X_1$.

---

**I would like to find a more elementary argument, which does not rely on Riemannian geometry.**

I think one possible approach is to show $X_2$ contains squares* with sides arbitrarily close to $2$ and $X_1$ does not.

This seems obvious, however a rigorous argument may not be trivial.

*Define a **square** with side $L$ in a metric space as: $\{x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3 \}$ such that: $d(x_i,x_{i+1})=L \, \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $d(x_0,x_2)=d(x_1,x_3)=L\sqrt{2}$

Comment: What about replacing squares by unit balls? Then suppose that there were an isometry, B_2(0) is mapped to some ball of diameter =2, but such a ball does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of squares I would have taken circles. But come to think of it, we might simply check for the existenc of an equilateral triangle of side length $2$.

- In $(0,2)\times\Bbb R$, the points $(a,-1)$, $(a,1)$, $(\sqrt 3+a,0)$ are such a triangle (provided $0<a<2-\sqrt 3$)
- In $(0,1)\times \Bbb R$, there is no such triangle: Suppose $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ are such a triangle and wlog. $y_1\le y_2\le y_3$. Then $y_3\le y_1+2$ and hence for one $i\in\{1,3\}$ we have $|y_2-y_i|\le 1$. Then  $(x_i-x_2)^2+(y_i-y_2)^2=4$ implies $|x_i-x_2|\ge\sqrt 3>1$, contradiction.